# How can I make a point-to-point VoIP call over Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, voip

I am searching for a way to make a point-to-point VoIP call between two Android devices without having any intermediate server (SIP server) or an Internet connection. I just have an access point (or multiple access point connect via LAN) and I want to make VoIP calls over Wi-Fi only. Is this possible?

Comment: I've rephrased your question a bit as app recommendations are generally off-topic (they are essentially shopping recommendations). However, if there is an app out there that supports this functionality it will be just as much a valid answer to this re-phrased question as your original one.

Comment: zix> Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [CSipSimple](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=csipsimple) to add a local SIP account on **both** phones without having the need for an intermediate SIP proxy (or server).

Add a general 'Local' account. You only have to provide a SIP username for it.

When that is done on both phones you can call the other phone:

- You have to know the IP address or dns name of the other phone
- You need to know the just set up SIP username of the other phone
- Dial 'SIPusername@IP-address' to call the other phone
- You need to switch from the initially shown number pad to the extended 'SIP uri' input window

Click on the green marked spot in the left image to navigate to the *SIP input activity* :

[image][image]

Comment: Have just tried CSipSimple's "Local" mode with "Wi-Fi hotspot" feature. [It fails](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26266/how-to-workaround-no-network-go-away-in-programs) because of "no network => won't listen 5060" idea...

Comment: Are you logged in into any wifi network? That's the only prerequisite (the OP already stated to have an access point)

Comment: The device is acting as Wi-Fi AP itself. One device is AP, other device is it's client. On client device all OK, but on AP device it's "no network".

Comment: The AP feature of Android is for tethering only, i.e. you can only use it to expose the 3G internet connection to other phones. Client to AP device communication is firewalled. You need to set up an ad-hoc wifi to get device-to-device connectivity. Just use a ad-hoc mode or a real AP instead.

Comment: But it's also good to connect two devices when they are "far away from civilization". They can network, but one of then "thinks" that there's no network. Especially strange for CSipSimple's "Local" mode which is designed for server-less operation.

Comment: it makes sense though. the ap network is normally a dead end as there are only clients which you supply with internet. from a programmatic POV it's most probably marked as unconnected. Say you want to download something and it would try that dead end. fail. the only active & real inet connection is 3g, which the local mode doesn't like. use ad hoc or a small portable ap

Comment: "use ad hoc" => Ad hoc mode configured in rooted device's Linux console is also "not a real network" for applications. "or a small portable ap" => Just to workaround this "too clever" logic? I want to configure things to work just as "wifi walkie-tolkie".

Comment: maybe mess around with 'ip route', give the wifi net an ip + a def. gateway or use a 3rd party app, barnacle wifi tether. Just my thoughts, have no experience with this kind of problem. i'd need to test more to be able to give a better advice, sorry. +: the OP already stated he has a dedicated AP. maybe also possible: use a 3rd phone as AP

Comment: 3rd phone will work. "ip route" is Linux-level thing, but the problems lies in Android level. It does not like when network is being configured not by Android.

Comment: Submitted an issue: http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/issues/detail?id=1843

Answer (score 3):

Use [uSipServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.joinsip.usipserver) + [SipDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua) (or whatever SIP client) configured at an explicit IP address.

Like one device has uSipServer, started Wi-Fi AP (in "Tethering" menu) and SipDroid connected to test1@127.0.0.1. Other device connects to Wi-Fi and use SIP account test2@192.168.43.1 and calls to "test1".

**Update:** Have just tested that this configuration *actually* works:

1. Put first device in "Portable Hotspot" mode (Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Tethering & portable hotspot -> Portable Wi-Fi hotspot)
2. Start uSipServer on the first device
3. Connect the second device to AP created by the first (Setting -> Wireless & networks -> Wi-Fi settings -> Wi-Fi networks -> "X10i" (or whatever name)
4. Start SipDroid on the second device, specifying, for example, "qqq" as user and "192.168.43.1" as SIP server. The indicator goes green.
5. Start SipDroid on the first device, speciftgin, for example, "eee" as user and "192.168.43.1" or "127.0.0.1" as server. The indicator stays yellow.
6. Can phone from the second device to the first, specifying "eee" in the lower call field; can phone from the first device to the second, specifying "qqq" in the lower call field. No external entities (like extra access points or cellular provider) involved.

I tried other SIP clients (like CSipSimple and Linphone), but they refuse to work on the first device when no "normal" network is configured. And SipDroid (which is fortunately dumb enough to overlook network "absence") is not codec-compatible with everything else I tried.

Note that if there are other network connections present, SipDroid may confuse them and send the wrong IP to it's peer resulting in "one way" phone. Test with only Wi-Fi hotstop/Wi-Fi client enabled.