# How to workaround "no network => go away" in programs?

Tags: networking

When neither Wi-Fi nor Mobile data connectin is turned on, the programs often tell "No network" and refusing to work (not even trying) although networking can still be available (Wifi in "hotspot" mode, USB reverse-tethered, some virtual network, etc.).

How to explicitly tell Android "There *is* network, I configured it myself" to make programs that rely on Android API to go?

Comment: Email the app developer, their app is buggy as they're checking for the wrong condition. Applications are able to check for mobile connection vs normal network so they can adapt to use less aggressive syncing strategy or avoid large downloads when on Mobile network which usually incur higher cost than Wifi.

Comment: The app just relies on Android API to detect network presense. Android tells "Neither Wi-Fi nor data nor any _known_ network present" and the program doesn't even try to use sockets/etc. It is more then one program, most notably Google Play Store and friends. The solution will be to make it report fake Wi-Fi or fake Mobile connection (not backed by Linux-level things) just to makes these apps happy.