# Use tablet as a Wi-Fi handsfree device?

Tags: wi-fi, tablet, calls, voip

My question is:
Is there any way to use Tablet as a hands free adapter by Wi-Fi?

With Access point created in the Tablet? "No internet" Device-To-Device lan connection.

For Example: 
call (smartphone) ---> Internal Forward ---> Skype (smartphone) ---> Wi-Fi (Forward) ---> Skype (tablet)

And the other way around:
Skype make call (tablet) ---> Wi-Fi (Forward) ---> Skype (smartphone) ---> Internal Forward ---> Phone call (smartphone).

Offline point-to-point VoIP call over Wi-Fi is possible: [How can I make a point-to-point VoIP call over Wi-Fi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22239/how-can-i-make-a-point-to-point-voip-call-over-wifi)

And receiving a call and transfer in the same phone to voip system... Is this possible?

Comment: You might look into [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/?setup=1#setup/). I think it will do what you want.

Comment: @SaintWacko outside the US?

Comment: I believe it works outside the US.