# How to make point to point VOIP call between two Android devices?

Tags: applications, wi-fi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a point-to-point VoIP call over Wifi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22239/how-can-i-make-a-point-to-point-voip-call-over-wifi)

I am searching for a way to make a point to point VOIP call between two Android devices without having any intermediate server(SIP server) or an internet connection.

I just have an access point (or multiple access point connect via LAN) and I want to make VOIP calls over Wi-Fi only.

Is that possible? And if it's possible is there any tutorial that could help me in applying such solution?

Comment: I've edited and rephrase your question to have it on-topic here. Developer questions or questions like "Is there an app for X?" are considered off-topic. (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for further details)